# Unable to find /proc/pid/io file in Android linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I want to know if /proc/pid/io is available in "Android" linux kernel. It says "/system/bin/sh: cat: /proc/9267/io: No such file or directory".

Comment: cat /proc/*/io gives the same message!

Comment: Or `cat /proc/self/io` or `cat /proc/$$/io`

Comment: Hi Basile. It dint work. It doesn't have any files. It works in my PC. May be it is not supported in Android kernel. There will be an alternate file which carries those information. I am browsing for that

Answer (score 1):

Could you please check if CONFIG_GCOV_KERNEL is enabled in kernel?
This configuration will give compiling of kernel/fs/proc/base.c, which contains information in /proc/[pid]/io

Comment: It might also be `CONFIG_TASKSTATS`