# how to have linux kernel export /proc/[pid]/io?

Tags: linux, proc

Im running linux on my board and have to read info in /proc/[pid]/io. But it is not found.

For ex:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/aa &
[1] 926
$ cat /proc/926/io
cat: /proc/926/io: No such file or directory
```

Which I need enable to have kernel export that?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Does /proc exist?  Does /proc/926 exist?

Comment: Yep, they do exist.

Comment: What kernel version?  (`uname -a`)

Comment: My kernel version is: Linux 4.1.17

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757400/unable-to-find-proc-pid-io-file-in-android-linux-kernel) suggests looking at the [kernel config](http://superuser.com/questions/287371/obtain-kernel-config-from-currently-running-linux-system).  (per the proc manpage, your kernel is new enough for /proc/pid/io)

Comment: I'm already try that, but it's still not work?

Comment: According to [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/how-to-enable-process-io-statistics-600777/), you need `CONFIG_TASKSTATS` enabled.  What value is it in `/boot/config*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/how-to-enable-process-io-statistics-600777/), you need `CONFIG_TASKSTATS` enabled in your kernel.

You can check your current kernel's config in [various ways](https://superuser.com/questions/287371/obtain-kernel-config-from-currently-running-linux-system) depending on distribution, but looking at `/boot/config-$(uname -r)` works in Redhat flavors.

If you don't have that option configured, you'll need to recompile your kernel, or investigate why your distro doesn't enable it.

Comment: Hmmm. Is there anything else that's necessary?

I just recompiled a 4.4 kernel (for an embedded system) and I have


`# zcat /proc/config.gz |grep TASKSTATS`

`CONFIG_TASKSTATS=y`

but I still don't have any /proc/<pid>/io.

(I have a lot of other stuff there, such as e.g. `/proc<pid>/stat`, but no `io`.)

Answer (score 3):

I just discovered that another thing is necessary.

I just recompiled a 4.4 kernel (for an embedded system) and enabling the `CONFIG_TASKSTATS` was not enough. I have to enable

```
CONFIG_TASKSTATS=y
CONFIG_TASK_XACCT=y
CONFIG_TASK_IO_ACCOUNTING=y
```

in order for the `/proc/<pid>/io` to appear.